# Find Nearest Bars From User's Postcode Using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am working on a project which requires me to find the nearest bars (pubs) within a parameter of 5 miles from the postcode (zipcode) of the user.

Is there a way to do this with Google Maps API to receive the data in an array, loop through it and them set up markers based on the lat and long received from the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find info on this particular feature of Google Maps API here:
https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search

This web service lets you search with a keyword while specifying your position and a search radius, and returns a list of places matching those parameters in a json or xml document.

Your example would look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=your_api_key&query="bar"&location=lat,lon&radius=8000
```

You'll need to replace

- `your_api_key` with the Google Maps API key for your application (you'll need one to use their web services)
- `lat,lon` with the coordinates of the user, that you can find with the geocoding web service as user agmangas suggested
- `8000` with the actual search radius, in meters (5 miles is about 8km).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the latitude and longitude from the zipcode of your user, this can be achieved using the [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Once you have this I'd say you need to use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) (*disclaimer: I have never actually used it*).

There's a code example under the *Nearby Search* section that I think more or less would fit your needs (you'd need to adapt it a bit):

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {

  // Replace with the latitude and longitude 
  // you got in a Geocoding Service request

  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  // Replace the place type you need ("bar")
  // Replace the radius (5 miles)

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```